# OkHTTPClient timeouts failing to work on Android

Tags: java, android, okhttp

In certain circumstances OkHTTPCLient fails to timeout and becomes 'stuck'.

Example code:

```
HTTPClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .build();
```

When mobile internet is poor some connections attempt forever.

I've had to put in timer calls to tear down the connections 'by hand' but this is far from acceptable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Increase you times in seconds ,as you mentioned now 10 seconds , server is not responding or giving response within 10 seconds , so make to to 60.

Comment: Sorry - I may not have been clear.  The client FAILS to timeout - is it keeps going way longer than 10 seconds.  I presume it's getting a very small amount of data from the connection holding it open.